# Transform DTM to text

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to transform the following DTM

```
pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,4,5],
              "t1": [0,0,1,1,0],
              "t2": [1,1,0,0,0],
              "t3": [1,0,1,0,0],
              "t4": [0,0,0,0,0]})
```

to this DF

```
pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,4,5],
              "text": ["t2, t3", "t2", "t1, t3", "t1", ""]})
>> 1  t2, t3
   2      t2
   3  t1, t3
```

My try is the following script

```
for col in df.columns: df = np.where(df[col] == 1, col, "")
df.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x), axis=1).str.split().apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
```

but I wonder if there is a more pythonic way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with filter columns by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) or by positions by `iloc`:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='t')

#df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
df = df[['ID']].join(df1.dot(df1.columns + ', ').str[:-2].rename('new'))
print (df)
   ID     new
0   1  t2, t3
1   2      t2
2   3  t1, t3
3   4      t1
4   5
```

Or by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('ID')
df = df1.dot(df1.columns + ', ').str[:-2].reset_index(name='new')
print (df)
   ID     new
0   1  t2, t3
1   2      t2
2   3  t1, t3
3   4      t1
4   5
```